# How do I use UPDATE...RETURNING correctly?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with a property that can be set, but which is supposed to expire after a certain amount of time.  If I run a query like this, it works as expected:

```
update MY_TABLE
set PROP = :value, PROP_TIMEOUT = dateadd (7 day to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
where ID = :id
```

But if I try to also retrieve the calculated timeout as part of the same query, it returns an empty result set and no records get updated in the table:

```
update MY_TABLE
set PROP = :value, PROP_TIMEOUT = dateadd (7 day to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
where ID = :id
returning PROP_TIMEOUT
```

Is this a bug in Firebird, or am I doing something wrong?  Using FBEMBED version 2.5.1.

Comment: In DSQL, a statement with a RETURNING clause always returns exactly one row. If no record was actually updated, the fields in this row are all NULL. This behaviour may change in a later version of Firebird. In PSQL, if no row was updated, nothing is returned, and the receiving variables keep their existing values.

Comment: An UPDATE statement modifying at most one row may optionally include a RETURNING clause in order to return values from the updated row.

Comment: @waleed: That doesn't explain why this query, which is supposed to modify exactly one row, ends up modifying nothing and returning an empty set when I add the RETURNING clause.

Comment: How do you connect to the DB, do you use API or some (Delphi?) component or...? Might be a bug/limitation in the "driver" too.

Comment: @ain: I'm seeing the same issue from multiple different connections and different programs.

Comment: I recommend to read this Firebird documentation page: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html

Comment: I just tested it on Firebird 2.5.2 (with flamerobin) and it works fine

Comment: When using Axtools (28.11.2006) Windows client, this does not return anything to the screen. But if you use Flamerobin (0.9.3), it returns the value.
(Firebird engine v.2.5.7)

Answer (score 2):

When you use RETURNING [fields] you need to specify INTO [variables].
INTO  is available only in PSQL

Example:

```
:
update MY_TABLE
set PROP = :value, PROP_TIMEOUT = dateadd (7 day to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
where ID = :id
returning PROP_TIMEOUT
into :ret_prop_timeout; -- variable needs to be declared
:
suspend; -- to return a output row
```

Comment: No, only if you're writing *in PSQL*.  The form I used is perfectly valid syntax for DSQL.